# Determine if the first character in a string is a $ and if it remove it and take everything else

Tags: php

All,
Say someone submits $1234, well I want to check to see if the first character is a $ and if it is I'd like to remove it and just use the rest of the string. So in this example, it would return 1234.

Also, is there a way to always add a .00 if the user doesn't enter it? So the end result is always 1234.00

So here are some inputs and how I'd like the desired results:

```
1234 = 1234.00
$1234 = 1234.00
$1234.23 = 1234.23
1234.23 = 1234.23
```

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: `substr()` and `number_format()` will help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`ltrim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php) and [`number_format`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

```
$newVal = number_format((float)ltrim('$1234.23', '$'), 2, '.', ''); // $newVal == '1234.23'
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is using `preg_match`, with regular expression: `~^\\$?(\\d+(?:[.,]\\d+)?)$~`, so entire code would be:

```
$match = array();
if( preg_match( '~^\\$?(\\d+(?:[.,]\\d+)?)$~', trim( $text), $match)){
    $yourValue = number_format( strtr( $match[1], array( ',' => '.')), 2, '.', '');
}
```

The another option is to use piece of code such as this:

```
$text = trim( strtr( $text, array( ',' => '.'))); // Some necessary modifications
// Check for $ at the beginning
if( strncmp( $text, '$', 1) == 0){
    $text = substr( $text, 1);
}
// Is it valid number?
if( is_numeric( $text)){
    $yourValue = number_format( $text, 2, '.', '');
}
```

Comment: That is an impressive regex, but I am not sure I would say that is the easiest way to do things. Also, that will put commas to group the thousands due to `number_format`'s default behavior.

Comment: @alecgorge thanks, fixed. I had a mistake in regexp too, I was missing `?` after `\\$`... I'm used to write much more complex regexpes from work so this seemed pretty "easy" to me. Hover, I like the second solution much better.